# How to make object or instances global

Tags: python

I am looking for a code by using which I can make objects global.
What I am looking is - suppose there is one file xyz.py which has code

```
import some_module

class classname:
    def __init__():
        pass

    def createobj():
        some_module_obj = some_module()
```

and there are other two files 1.py and 2.py which has code
**1.py**

```
import xyz

obj =  classname()
obj.sayhi()
```

**2.py**

```
import xyz

obj.sayhi()
```

I want to use the same object in 2.py created once in 1.py

Can anyone help me to know how can i achieve this.

Thanks,
Vipul

Answer (score 1):

2.py

```
import xyz
print xyz.obj
```

or

```
from xyz import obj
print obj
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a *name* which is known and refers to the same object in all modules.  Each module has its own `global` namespace.

But you can of course access the namespace of other modules by using qualified names.

EDIT:

Using module names like `1` (i. e. in files called `1.py`) or similar is no good idea because a number cannot be used as an identifier.  Qualified names like `1.obj` are a syntax error.  So I will use the files `one.py` and `two.py` instead, then I can access `one.obj` without this trouble.

If in file `one.py` you have sth like

```
obj = "foo"
```

then you can import this in file `two.py`:

```
import one
print one.obj  # or use it any way you like
```

If you import it like this:

```
from one import obj
```

Then you will still have the same object:

```
print obj == one.obj  # will print True (they are equal)
print obj is one.obj  # will print True (they are the same)
```

but in a different variable named obj:

```
obj = "bar"
print obj, one.obj  # will print "bar foo"
```

That the two variables are not the same only matters in case you assign sth to them.

So, if you want to be able to change the value (and have the change have effect in all using modules), you can either use the qualified name (`one.obj`) everywhere:

```
import one
one.obj = "bar"
```

or, instead of assigning a new value to the variable, you can *change* the existing value.  This will also have effect in all using modules:

`one.py`:

```
obj = [ "foo" ]
```

`two.py`:

```
from one import obj
obj[0] = "bar"
```

This will also have effect in `one.py` even if our `obj` is a different variable than `one.obj` because both variables reference the same list.

If possible, I would propose to use the version using qualified names of course because the reference thing is hiding the mechanism and will probably surprise the next developer.

Comment: thanks for the information. Can you please share some sample code on how to achieve this

Comment: I extended my answer.